# error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"controls"' can't be used to index type 'AbstractControl<any, any>'

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am getting below error from my angular reactive form.  Is there anything I am missing? I am facing error in the second nested form.

```
 error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"controls"' can't be used to index type 'AbstractControl<any, any>'.
  Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl<any, any>'.

19                 <tr *ngFor="let data of item.get('rows')['controls']; let j = index" formGroupName="j">
```

TS file

```
public usersForm!: FormGroup;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() :void {
    this.usersForm = new FormGroup({
      users: new FormArray([
        new FormGroup({
          key: new FormControl(),
          rows: new FormArray([
            new FormGroup({
              updatedBy: new FormControl(this.formatFormValue('')),
              updatedAt: new FormControl(this.formatFormValue('')),
              comment: new FormControl(this.formatFormValue('')),
            }),
          ]),
        }),
      ]),
    });
  }

 getFormControl() {
    return this.usersForm .get('users') as FormArray;
  }
```

Template File

```
<form [formGroup]="usersForm ">
    <div formArrayName="users">
       <table *ngFor="let item of getFormControl().controls; let i = index"  [class.table_margin]="i>0">
        <div formGroupName="i">
            <tr>
                <th>{{item.get('key').value}}</th>
            </tr>
            <span formArrayName="rows">
                <tr *ngFor="let data of item.get('rows')['controls']; let j = index" formGroupName="j">
                    <td >
                        <input type="text" formControlName="comment">
                    </td>
                </tr>
          </span>
      </div>
     </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have also tried item.get('rows').controls, thats not working as well.

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix the error would be to define a getter for the "rows" in the component:

```
       getFormControl() {
        return this.usersForm .get('users') as FormArray<FormGroup>;
       }
       get rows() {
        return this.getFormControl().controls['rows'] as FormArray<FormGroup>;
       }
```

and then to use it in the html template while iterating the rows:

```
 <span formArrayName="rows">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let data of rows.controls; let index = index">
       <ng-container [formGroupName]="index">
         <td >
           <input type="text" formControlName="comment">
         </td> 
       </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </span>
```

or you can simply typecast it in the template:

```
<span formArrayName="rows">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let data of (item.get('rows') as FormArray<FormGroup>).controls; let index = index">
       <ng-container [formGroupName]="index">
         <td >
           <input type="text" formControlName="comment">
         </td> 
       </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </span>
```

Basically the error states as far as I understand it (I'm new to the Angular so be merciful) states that the element don't have defined type you can iterate (you are trying to access index 'controls' of AbstractControl which doesn't exist) hence "any" you are trying to access index 'controls' of AbstractControl (https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl).
So you need to specify that you are iterating a FormArray.

Here is the angular guide on FormArray: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-form-array/

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the **users** controls index to get the dynamic **rows**

```
  get getFormControl() {
    return this.usersForm.get('users') as FormArray;
  }

  getRows(index: number) {
    return this.getFormControl.controls[index].get('rows') as FormArray;
  }
```

and change your HTML to this

```
  <form [formGroup]="usersForm">
    <div formArrayName="users">
      <table *ngFor="let item of getFormControl.controls; let i = index"  [class.table_margin]="i>0">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
          <tr>
            <th>{{item.value.key}}</th>
          </tr>
          <span formArrayName="rows">
            <tr *ngFor="let data of getRows(i).controls; let j = index" [formGroupName]="j">
              <td >
                <input type="text" formControlName="comment">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </span>
        </div>
      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
```